# Why is my man page formatted incorrectly ONLY when viewed with man?

Tags: linux, distribution, groff

I am writing a man page for a program, the source looks like this:

```
.TH prog 1 "26 AUG 2010" "Version 0.1" "Center header"
.NAME
prog \- runs a program
.SH SYNOPSIS
.B prog
```

When I use

```
$ groff -Tascii -man source.txt | more
```

the output is pretty much as expected.

When I use:

```
$ groff -Tascii -man source.txt > prog.1 && \
sudo cp prog.1 /usr/local/man/man1/ && man prog
```

the ouput looks like this:

prog(2)                                                                                Center                                 header
prog(2)

**NAME**
    prog - runs a program

Version          0.1
                                                    
26
            
AUG
                               
2010

I'm on Ubuntu 8.04. I've verified that it isn't the pager because I also tried `man -P more` and still had the same odd output. What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `man` runs `groff` itself internally - it's not expecting you to have done it already. Just copy your `source.txt` straight into `/usr/local/man/man1/prog.1`, and it should work fine.

Comment: Further, to test with the `man` command, run `man -l prog.1` (or `source.txt` if you prefer that name).